# How to use exists with a subquery?

Tags: mysql

Hi i'm trying to Display all drinks each manufacturer is producing except the carbonated one's using exists and a subquery but its giving me a empty set please help me out

```
mysql> 'select * from drink';
+----------------+------------+----------------+
| name           | type       | manf           |
+----------------+------------+----------------+
| Coca-cola zero | carbonated | Coca-Cola      |
| Mirinda        | carbonated | PepsiCo        |
| Big Apple      | carbonated | Murree Brewery |
| Big Lemon      | carbonated | Murree Brewery |
| Big Orange     | carbonated | Murree Brewery |
| Peach Malt     | malt       | Murree Brewery |
| Lemon Malt     | malt       | Murree Brewery |
| Apple Malt     | malt       | Murree Brewery |
| New Coke       | carbonated | Coca-Cola      |
| Diet Coke      | carbonated | Coca-Cola      |
| Pepsi          | carbonated | PepsiCo        |
| Fruita vitals  | Juice      | Nestle         |
| Twister        | Juice      | Shezan         |
| Nescafe        | cofee      | Nestle         |
| Cappuccino     | Cofee      | Gloria Jeans   |
| Caffe Latte    | Cofee      | Gloria Jeans   |
| Flat White     | Cofee      | Gloria Jeans   |
+----------------+------------+----------------+
17 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Query i tried but its not giving me a result

```
SELECT * FROM drink WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM drink WHERE drink.type = 'carbonated');
```

Comment: Are you sure you explained the question correctly? EXISTS would be used if it were "show all drinks except those from manufacturers who also make carbonated drinks"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of your goal.

If it's to select all the drinks form all manufacturers *except* manufacturers which have carbonated drinks do this.

```
Select
   * 
From Drink d1
Where Not Exists
    (   Select * 
        From Drink d2 
        Where d2.Manf = d1.Manf
          And d2.Type = 'carbonated');
    )
```

If it's just selecting all the drinks which are not carbonated it's simpler.

```
Select
   * 
From Drink 
Where Type <>'carbonated'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a case for `EXISTS` - a simple

```
SELECT * FROM drink WHERE `type`<>'carbonated'
```

will do.

If this is not what you are after, you need to update your question to be more specific.

Comment: i have done this but my teacher's question requirement is to do it with a exists and a subquery  so please help me with this !!


Query 1: Display all drinks each manufacturer is producing except the carbonated one's.
Query 2: Write the above query using Exists operator and using a subquery.
your answer is of query1 which i have done it by myself ..got stuck in query2

Answer (score 0):

What Eugen said is correct, using a EXISTS for this is insanely ineffiecent, and would generaly be just wrong. But if you really want to make it work it might look like this :

```
SELECT * FROM drink A WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM drink B WHERE A.name = B.name AND A.manf = B.manf AND B.type = 'carbonated'
);
```

(I only give this answer because I remeber being asked for similar stupid queries in my graduate databases course when going over relational algebra, so I think I have idea why you're asking this. )

Comment: Thanks gbtimmon it worked !! and i know that is but my teacher's requirement was that :(

Answer (score 0):

do not use subquery if the simple query is doing the same thing

```
SELECT * FROM drink WHERE `type` <> 'carbonated'
```

subquery will slow your system and also there is no need of subquery for doing this. These techniques enhance your application speed. Think about future if you have fifteen thousand records subquery will slow down your application.